# (Causal) Set notation round brackets vs square brackets?

Tags: general-relativity, mathematical-physics, notation

In many (quite old) papers & books I have been reading recently in the causal theory of general relativity (e.g. *On the structure of causal spaces*, Kronheimer & Penrose, 1967) I find sets being defined in a "function-like" way with round brackets thus,

$J^{+}(a)=\{x:a <x\}$

and also with square brackets, thus,

$J^{+}[A]=\cup\{J^{+}(a):a\in A\}$

It seems to me that [ ] indicates that the argument is a set and ( ) indicates the argument is a point to avoid writing e.g. $J[\{x\}]$ (or similar with "( )" ).

Is this correct and what is the origin of this notation? Is it still current, or what is the preferred notation now?

In more recent papers (e.g. *Global Spacetime Structure*, Manchak, 2011) I see e.g. $D(S)$ where $S$ is explicitly a set and am not sure whether these are personal preferences in evidence or a shift in accepted notation.

If one wishes to define a set with respect to a curve in some manifold $M$, for which the usual specification would be e.g. $\gamma: I \rightarrow M$ what should one write given that $\gamma$ is a function distinguished from its image $\gamma(some\ interval)$? I'm sure I've seen e.g. $D[\gamma]$ with an apology about "abuse of notation" - what should it be?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question (v1) (_What is the preferred notation now?_)  as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Yes, I saw; I put a question in meta about this because I didn't know how to discuss it with you: in short,  it may be an opinion but if that's a fact, I'd like to know :) Writing a paper for submission and must try to use current/correct notation or make a personal choice if that is an allowable choice. Would appreciate your help in working out how to proceed.

Comment: Also the answer to the question (v1) _Is this correct?_ seems to be _Yes, you are right,_ which tends to make it unsuitable for the SE Q&A format, where longer answers are preferred.  Moreover, the question (v1) _What is the origin of this notation?_ seems to be more about history than physics.

Comment: What's the motivation for this question? I mean, why do you care, it's just notations?

Comment: @MBN It's more than just idle curiosity - I understand what is meant in the the papers I'm reading, but I'm writing a paper: I'd like to avoid trivial referee objections and, since I don't count as a professional physicist, not to be seen as making errors that suggest I haven't done my research. I'm bothered enough about potential errors as it is and don't won't to compound/complicate things.

Comment: @Qmechanic. If I were to ask "Do the majority of papers/major recent papers still use this notation?" would that satisfactorily shift it from the domain of history and opinion to matter of fact? Or, should I ask, "Given that I wish to define a symbol that acts on sets or acts on individual set members, what notation should I use and why?" Or something else. I feel you know what I wish to know and expect that you could more easily offer an acceptable question that would deliver an acceptable answer than I.

Comment: [...] I feel that, since AFAIK  there is no equivalent of the Academie Francaise for math notation, any such questions are by definition going to be matters of opinion, and, since they seek opinions about important acceptable practice - as evidenced by actual practice - rather than unascertainable (non-existent?) facts, the question should (maybe subject to some modification) be given the benefit of the doubt. Whilst one can make up notation (~Private Languages) it's not particularly conducive to efficient communication...

Comment: Related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/7736/2451

Comment: Hawking & Ellis, Wald, O'Neil, Beem et al., and Minguzzi & Sanchez use $()$. Since these are the standard references in the field, I'd go with that. It seems Penrose (1971) uses $[]$, but that's the only standard reference that doesn't.

Comment: @ocelo7 Thanks, just the sort of answer I was looking for; Penrose isn't alone (e.g. Geroch circa 1970) but I agree with the "standard references" assessment and am happy to accept it. Thanks again.

Comment: @JulianMoore I haven't had reason to look at Geroch, AFAIK all of the proofs therein are also in Hawking & Ellis and the others I mentioned.